# Word for visiting infant and parents

Tags: word-request

In Dutch, we have the word *kraamvisite* or *kraambezoek*, which is a visit to a newborn baby and his/her parent(s).  This word is lacking in my dictionary.  Google Translate makes it *maternity visit*, but judging from the word that's quite related to the mother.

English is quite rich in words, is there a word for such a visit, or must one be verbose and *I will visit the newborn infant and his/her parents*?

Comment: One might refer to a *[natal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/natal#Adjective)* visit

Comment: @jwpat7: I can't find a single instance of *natal visit* in Google Books that isn't actually *pre-natal* or *post-natal*. And every one of those where the context is clear appears to be referring to the expectant/new parent(s) either attending maternity facilities or being visited by a medical professional.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a specific word for it, but I have never come across it.  You are correct in that a maternity visit is specific to the mother, but it's more common to say something like "to see the baby".  I don't think I've ever heard someone say they were going to visit the newborn and his parents; it's always "to see".

Answer (score 0):

Although there might be a specific word, it is not common. Consider for example the recent reports on the birth of Kate and Prince William's new son, as reported by the BBC, which shows common idom of saying to visit the parents and child:

> Prince Charles has visited the Duke and Duchess of Cambridge and his new grandson in hospital in west London.

( cite: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-23421388 )